# Whats the best way to create a self-referential association in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, self-reference

In my project I am dealing with objects called Workflows. Every Workflow can have many subflows (Workflows that it calls). At the same time every workflow (Including ones with sub flows) may also act as a Superflow that is calling the sub-flows and may have many Superflows that call it as a sub flow.

I am currently trying to do this by using a join table through a model called FlowRelation.

I have followed every tutorial I can find and read every article I can find and I still can't get this working.

Workflow Model:

```
class Workflow < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :superflow, :class_name => 'Workflow'
 has_many :subflows, :class_name => 'Workflow', :foreign_key => 'subflow_id'
end
```

FlowRelation Model:

```
class FlowRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :workflow
 belongs_to :flow, :class_name => "Workflow"
end
```

Inside my workflows edit.html.erb (Using SimpleForm)

```
<%= simple_form_for @workflow, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :workflow_id %>
<%= error_span(@workflow[:workflow_id]) %>

<%= f.association :subflows, :include_blank => t('.select_workflow') %>
<%= error_span(@workflow[:subflow_id]) %>  

<%= f.association :superflow, :include_blank => t('.select_workflow') %>
<%= error_span(@workflow[:superflow_id]) %>
```

And my Workflow Controller is pretty straightforward

```
def new
  @workflow = Workflow.new
end

def edit
  @workflow = Workflow.find(params[:id])
  @workflow.save    
end
```

Currently, when I attempt to save new sub_flows to an existing or new Workflow, nothing ever gets saved. Nothing shows up in the database, and I see no error.

I also have a FlowRelationsController

```
class FlowRelationsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :set_flow_relation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @flow_relation = current_workflow.flow_relations.build(:flow_id => params[:flow_id])
if @flow_relation.save
  flash[:notice] = "Added flow."
  redirect_to root_url
else
  flash[:error] = "Unable to add flow."
  redirect_to root_url
end
end
```

If I attempt to create an add sub_flow button to my workflow index with

```
<%= link_to "Add Subflow", flow_relations_path(:flow_id => workflow), :method => :post %>
```

My flow_relations table remains empty as well. and I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_workflow' for #   
<FlowRelationsController:0x007f70154921e0>
```

I know its a bunch of pieces, but I'm completely stuck, been hitting my head against a wall on this one for days. Anyone see something I'm missing here? I've been trying to implement something similar to what was described on RailsCasts here with no success: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast

Please HELP!

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so update. I realized I was doing something stupid as a result of following a tutorial that was a bit different from my situation.  Here is what I'm working with now:

              <%= link_to "Add Subflow", new_flow_relations(:subflow_id => workflow.id), :method => :new %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding a couple different things. I thought I'd answer my own question to help bring clarity to any others who may be in the same boat.

1st major issue I had above was in the FlowRelationsController. I was using an object called current_workflow which didnt exist. This happened due to following the only video i could find online about this topic at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association. This is a create resource, but is not entirely the same as what I was trying to accomplish. The current_workflow object wasnt being created in my case because I was starting from an index and not a workflow details section of my application

Now, as to how to accomplish my original goal. Here is what I ended up with:

Workflow Model

```
has_many :flow_relations
has_many :subflows, :through => :flow_relations
```

FlowRelation Model

```
self.primary_key = :workflow_id

belongs_to :workflow
belongs_to :subflow, :class_name => 'Workflow'
```

Inside of my simpleForm used for creation and editing of workflows. (This was a pretty key piece to understand. - doing the association to subflows with a collection of all workflow objects.

```
  <%= f.association :subflows, collection: Workflow.all, prompt: "Select Subflows" %>
  <%= error_span(@workflow[:subflow_id]) %>
```

The Workflow controller stayed mostly the same with one key difference due to Rails 4. - I had to change the workflow_params to permit!. I did this on both the Worfklow Controller and the FlowRelations controller. Not sure I understand still how this should be configured for better security, but in this particular application, security is not an issue as its to be run internally.

```
def new
  @workflow = Workflow.new
end

def edit
  @workflow = Workflow.find(params[:id])
  @workflow.save    
end 

def workflow_params
  #params.require(:workflow).permit(:workflow_id, :flow_relations, :re_workflow_id, :name, :description, :superflow_id, :client_id, :variable_id, :required_variable_id, :flow_file)
 params.require(:workflow).permit!
end
```

I removed the add subflow button, since now it could be done through the standard create or edit actions

Its a bunch of stuff, but basically, the end result is I now have a Workflow object that can contain mnay subflows all of which can be a member of many Workflows, all within a single Workflow class and a FlowRelations class for handeling the join.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into any of the other self-referential model stuff you're doing here, the error you see is a controller error. It doesn't know about 'current_workflow'. My guess is that in your 'set_flow_relation' before callback, you are setting @current_workflow. I cannot be sure without seeing the rest of your controller code.

Once that is fixed, please post any follow up problems you have.